# What and How Java framework be built?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, frameworks

I know this question is a bit silly.

I am a Java Programmer that never look into Java source code before, I have been using Java (official) framework (for example like javax.swing.*, java.util.*, java.collection.* and blah blah) to build some app.

Now I try to look into the Java source code (I am the victim of black-box programming paradigm) and found that the source code is totally written in Java. Now, I am confused that, what is the framework that is being used by Java (the one that in Java source code, I know a bit confused here) to form the framework that we are using so much?

Sincerely I expected to see some assembly-kind of code in Java source but in fact it is not. I 'feel' that the normal framework (java.*.*, javax.*.*) that we use are not the lowest entry point to the JVM. There must be something 'lower' than that.

Anyone can explain about this?

Comment: I just can't understand how can the Java framework that we are using actually using itself as a framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the Java library (what you call the Framework) is written in Java.  The JVM that interprets the compiled bytecode is implemented in C++ for the most part, and the library does contain "native" methods written in a lower-level language (C or C++).

Methods are written in a lower-level language for only two reasons: platform dependencies (things that have to be different on each platform), and performance (things that get used all the time and benefit from being native code).

The end result is that almost all of the library is platform-agnostic and doesn't have to be rewritten for each platform. The scope of non-Java code is limited to only the stuff that HAS to be platform specific.

Comment: Don't know if it counts as framework, but Swing makes use of DirectX and OpenGL depending on the platform...

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert but...

The JVM converts Java source code to machine code.  So that's the lowest level, once you have something that runs Java source (the JVM) then you can make a framework around it (in Java).

That said, there are still some native OS function calls - sorry I don't know much about them.

FYI .NET is the same, framework written in .NET with native calls peppered around.

Answer (score 1):

Java source code: some code written in Java program language

javac: a command line utility, used to compile Java source code to class file(which contains bytecode)

jvm: load class file, and executing the bytecode in that file.

bytecode: a instruction set, looked like assembly language. One instruction's length is one byte(That's why it's called bytecode).

JNI:  Java Native Interface(mostly written by C/C++), an interface to expend Java program abilities, which is difficult/unable to implements using java, such as some program about OS.

bytecode is like this:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code:
    0: ldc           #16                 // String a a \"fsd  fsd\" sfd gfd  \"fs  d\"
    2: astore_1
    3: getstatic     #18                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    6: aload_1
    7: invokestatic  #24                 // Method t:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    10: invokevirtual #28                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    13: return
```

You can get the code above with command utility javap.